# cobject in partial no output (Typo3, Fluid)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-8.x

I was following this tutorial and came across a problem: https://wiki.typo3.org/T3Doc/Fluidtemplate_by_example#The_Layout-Switch

The partial should be rendered twice. However, only the first partial is rendered. The second one, having the "lib.menu" as argument, is not rendered.

Template:

```
<f:section name="pageInfoBoxes">
  <f:render partial="Colorbox" arguments="{boxHeader : 'Abstract', boxContent : '{data.title}', boxColor : 'blue'}" />
  <f:render partial="Colorbox" arguments="{boxHeader : 'Subpages', boxContent : '{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.menu')->f:format.raw()}', boxColor : 'red'}" />
</f:section>
```

Partial (colorbox.html):

```
<div class="box box-{boxColor}">
  <h3>{boxHeader}</h3>
  <div class="contains">
    {boxContent}
  </div>
</div>
```

Layout:

```
<header>
  <h1>
    <f:link.page pageUid="67" title="Nuremberg Shop">Nuremberg Shop</f:link.page>
  </h1>
  <f:render section="topMenu" />
</header>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">fileadmin/.../Layouts/
    <f:render section="content"/>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
    <f:if condition="{contentRight}">
      <f:then><f:render section="contentRight"/></f:then>
      <f:else><f:render section="pageInfoBoxes"/></f:else>
    </f:if>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
<!-- here some stuff for footer... -->
</footer>
```

I can't figure out why this line is not rendered correctly:

```
  <f:render partial="Colorbox" arguments="{boxHeader : 'Subpages', boxContent : '{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.menu')->f:format.raw()}', boxColor : 'red'}" />
```

I tried different syntaxes, with no luck.

Comment: What happen, if you only render the partial with the cObject? Is it a problem of rendering zwo times the same partial or a problem of the syntax of the second partial?

Comment: When I escape lib.menu (\'lib.menu\') then I receive a frontend output. However, it shows the HTML and the HTMl source looks like this:     &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;index.php?id=67&quot;&gt;Home&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;

Comment: Sorry. You misunderstood me. I mean rendering only the second partial like this: <f:section name="pageInfoBoxes">
  <f:render partial="Colorbox" arguments="{boxHeader : 'Subpages', boxContent : '{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.menu')->f:format.raw()}', boxColor : 'red'}" />
</f:section>. Then what happen?

Comment: I see, sorry. There is no output at all.

Comment: Please add lib.menu in your question. What happens, if you use `<f:render partial="Colorbox" arguments="{boxHeader : 'Subpages', boxContent : '{pages -> f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.menu')}', boxColor : 'red'}" />` ?

Comment: nothing, no output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things of note:

First, when you have something like the following,

```
boxContent: '{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.menu')->f:format.raw()}'
```

you have to escape the inner quotes with a backslash:

```
boxContent: '{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:\'lib.menu\')->f:format.raw()}'
```

There isn't really any good way in fluid to prevent these cases, especially if you nest it even further. Though you could use the f:variable ViewHelper to set a temporary variable and use that as boxContent argument instead.

The second part, that you mentioned in your comments:

You have to apply the f:format.raw at the location where you output your boxContent.

So it should instead be something like:

```
boxContent: '{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:\'lib.menu\')}'
```

and in the partial you do:

```
{boxContent -> f:format.raw()}
```

The ViewHelpers have an option to disable the escaping interceptor, but that only works, if the result of the viewhelper is printed directly. If you store the result in a variable and output the variable later, the escaping still applies to the output of the variable.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Frontend output looks normal now. Thanks again.